# Changing my width with % in css changing bootstrap flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I got a strange problem.
I added to my div container a

> d-flex justify-content-between container

with one side text and the other images.
but when I'm changing the width with % for example (width:5%) the flex gets strange and everything is going to the end.

some point: when im changing the width with vh vw or px its working but I need the %. what can I do?

JSX:

```
<section className='footer-area'>
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-between container'>
          <div className='address'>
            <h4>Home@re-friendly.com</h4>
            <h4>ארלוזרוב 11, רמת גן</h4>
          </div>
          <div className='mw-3 share '>
            <img
              src={facebookLogo}
              className='img-fluid'
              alt='Responsive image'
              onClick={() =>
                window.open(
                  "https://www.facebook.com/"
                )
              }
            />
            <img
              src={whatsappLogo}
              className='img-fluid'
              alt='Responsive image'
              onClick={() => window.open("https://wa.me/+972505710373")}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
.img-fluid {
  margin: 2vh;
  max-width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The strange footer

[image: The strange footer]

How it should be:
[image]
(did it with vh but i need it with %)

Comment: It would be easier to spot the problem if you can provide a working snippet demostrating your problem. Could you try to use `flex: 0 0 5%` instead of `width: 5%`

Answer (score 0):

For `flex` children `flex` property instead of width.

so to achieve `5%` width use `flex: 0 0 5%;` in your css property

Comment: didn't understand your answer... I need to put it on the parent element or on the child(tried on both without success.)

Comment: My answer sets the width on a flex element child. with bootstrap `d-flex justify-content-between` you should be able to achieve the desired result. Can you please share the CSS of these classes? `address`  `mw-3 share` might help in tracing the problem

Answer (score -1):

```
  .img-fluid {
    margin: 2vh;
    max-width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
     }
```